# Python, divide all numbers in a 2d list by 10 and return a 2d list

Tags: python

I wrote this solution, and coming from Ruby it seems very elegant. However, is this the way a python programmer would do it?

```
a = [[2,3,4], [9,1,2]]
print map(lambda(i): map(lambda(p): p/10.0,i), a)
```

And... what if instead of 10, I wanted to use the total of all the values in the nested 2d list?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's generally solved by using comprehensions, in this case a nested list-comprehension:

```
>>> from __future__ import division   # for python-2.x compatibility
>>> [[item / 10 for item in subl] for subl in a]
[[0.2, 0.3, 0.4], [0.9, 0.1, 0.2]]
```

That's probably faster than `map` and avoids all the `lambda` functions.

> what if instead of 10, I wanted to use the total of all the values in the nested 2d list?

Calculate the total using `sum` and a nested generator expression:

```
>>> sum_ = sum(item for subl in a for item in subl)
>>> [[item / sum_ for item in subl] for subl in a]
[[0.09523809523809523, 0.14285714285714285, 0.19047619047619047],
 [0.42857142857142855, 0.047619047619047616, 0.09523809523809523]]
```

---

But with NumPy arrays it's even easier. NumPy a 3rd party package but very powerful and fast:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> arr = np.array(a)
>>> arr / 10.   # element-wise division
array([[ 0.2,  0.3,  0.4],
       [ 0.9,  0.1,  0.2]])

>>> arr / arr.sum()  # sum over all elements then element-wise division
array([[ 0.0952381 ,  0.14285714,  0.19047619],
       [ 0.42857143,  0.04761905,  0.0952381 ]])
```

Answer (score 2):

Another approach is to use [numpy](http://www.numpy.org/), since it deals with arrays and its operators work on each element of the array by default.

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: a = np.array([[2,3,4], [9,1,2]])

In [3]: a/10
Out[3]: 
array([[ 0.2,  0.3,  0.4],
       [ 0.9,  0.1,  0.2]])
```

To divide by the sum of all the numbers, do

```
In [6]: a/a.sum()
Out[6]: 
array([[ 0.0952381 ,  0.14285714,  0.19047619],
       [ 0.42857143,  0.04761905,  0.0952381 ]])
```

Comment: I hear a lot about numpy. Would it be considered overkill if this is all I needed it for? Plus I want the result to be a list. At least I think I do...

Comment: @pitosalas Once you start using it, you will find it useful for a lot of things. It has the ability to make a lot of numerical code quite compact and fast. And for example it can also do things like discrete fourier transforms. It makes working with multi-dimensional lists very easy.

Comment: Note my update to the question above. What if instead of divide by 10, I want to divide by the sum of all the integers? IOW normalize it?

Comment: @pitosalas `numpy` is meant for working with fixed-sized, *true-multidimensional arrays* of numeric values, and numpy arrays have different performance advantages compared to the vanilla Python `list` data structure, which in CPython is implemented as a finely-tuned dynamic array that can hold heterogeneous data types, with amortized constant-time `.append` and `.pop` operations. 

Also, if your 2d list can be "staggered", numpy does not support this (elegantly), and then vanilla python `list` is the way to go.

If you are doing linear algebra on huge arrays, then go with `numpy`.

Answer (score 1):

List comprehensions are much more elegant and would be considered more Pythonic (with their better readability):

```
>>> [[x/10.0 for x in lst] for lst in a]
[[0.2, 0.3, 0.4], [0.9, 0.1, 0.2]]
```

Also, note that `map` won't return a list in Python 3, it returns an iterator object. You'll need to call `list` on each of the map objects to have them evaluated into list. The list comp returns the same result across versions.